# Defining "Penon Infinitesimals".

Tags: reference-request, definition, topos-theory, infinitesimals, constructive-mathematics

In [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKWYa9sc5UI) (which is accompanied by [these slides](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/quantum/slides/clap2-peterjohnstone.pdf)), right near the end (so page 9 in the pdf of the slides; I don't think you have to watch the lecture), P. Johnstone refers to the "Penon infinitesimals", the set of which (I interpret as being) "defined" as follows:

> $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \neg\neg(x=0)\}$.

These look *phenomenal*. I'd like to (confirm that this is indeed the definition and) find out more about them but nearly everything I've seen on them is behind some pay-wall or another. So, what *exactly* are they?

Comment: Search for Smooth Infinitesimal Analysis, and the book A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis by Bell.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @mt_ "Penon" is not mentioned anywhere in the suggested reference.

Comment: But I can confirm that your interpretation is correct. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=w02XaOa_0HAC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=penon+infinitesimal&source=bl&ots=Hk3wT1Lv0z&sig=OCXe4cUmoS5JarTXvpZRs0jMwDs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C5kkU9GQC4uJogS-0YLgAw&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=penon%20infinitesimal&f=false). (This is from "Mathematical logic and theoretical computer science", D. Kueker et al., eds., pg. 119. The original reference is [this one](http://www.worldcat.org/title/i-de-linfinitesimal-au-local/oclc/689853744).)

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect (and the comment by @mt_ was really helpful nonetheless).

Comment: Also check out a relevant fine [blog post by Andrej Bauer](http://math.andrej.com/2008/08/13/intuitionistic-mathematics-for-physics/) (if you are in a hurry, scroll down to _Smooth infinitesimal analysis_). If you want more details, check out [Mike Shulman's pizza seminar notes](http://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/sdg-pizza-seminar.pdf). They are very accessible.

Comment: Thank you, @IngoBlechschmidt. That's all fascinating. I've removed the "nonstandard-analysis" tag now thanks to the blog post :)